# Weird spacing between spans if first span has last character space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I noticed this issue caused by localisation typo - there was a space left in the end of the translation, which caused an unexpected effect. I've reproduced it [in the following fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8w6ex37/):

```
<style>
.label {
  display: inline;
  padding: .2em .6em .3em;
  font-size: 75%;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-radius: .25em;
  background-color: #d9534f;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
</style>
<div>
    <p>Label with last character space</p>
    <span class="label">Label </span>
    <span>some text</span>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Label without space</p>
    <span class="label">Label</span>
    <span>some text</span>
</div>
```

The label class is taken from the twitter bootstrap version 3.1.1.

Could you please help me to understand why span with a last character space sticks to the next one, but when space removed from inside span it is back to normal?

Comment: @PeeHaa: yes, I read question once again and removed my comment while you wrote yours one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In HTML more white-space characters (`\t`, `\n`, , etc.) are replaced by a space (exactly one space). In the first code this space is inside `span` and there is no reason to render another one space after `span`.

In the second case, space is rendered correctly after `span`, because is the first.

Comment: So it's because it's an inline element?

Comment: @PeeHaa: partly, spaces in blocks will behave a little bit differently. While using plain text and/or inline elements, just the first space is rendered.

Comment: Thank you for explanation! Though it's strange, I expected spaces to take into account closing tags - `</span>` in this case. Obviously it's not happening for inline elements.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the width of the label is increased when you have introduced the blank space for last character.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I see weird space, but I have added `inline-block` to the label. Now you don't see that weird space .

```
.label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .2em .6em .3em;
  font-size: 75%;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-radius: .25em;
  background-color: #d9534f;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c8w6ex37/3/

Comment: Thank you @BaTmaN, I've fixed the issue by removing the space from translation. I'm curious about why it is happening.

Comment: @DmitryEvseev http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/stylesheets/cssspacing.html This may clarify your doubt.